# Why doesn't ScriptReference override Equals?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I was wondering if there is a good reason for [`ScriptReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference.aspx) not to override `Equals`. It would certainly make life in [`ScriptReferenceCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference.aspx)s easier (e.g. `Contains`), would it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has too many properties that may vary to make it viable to use some form of value based equality.

Note also it isn't sealed hence its sub-types may introduce further properties which would invalidate any existing equality code and hence make equality testing even more complex.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is either the framework team forgot, which is unlikely but could occur.  Or they just didn't see a need, normally with reference objects you don't override the Equals method unless you are using some kind of entity object that is expected to compare across different references, such as a string or a Uri.  Granted it would have been easy to implement this because it only takes two values.  So to be honest, I don't know why.